# Remove parent node in xml if child node contains a particular string

Tags: xml

I have an xml document:

```
<xml>
<duplication>
 <file path="C:\Hello\Test.Designer.cs" />
 <file path="C:\Hello\Demo.Designer.cs" />
</duplication>
<duplication>
 <file path="C:\Hello\Test.cs" />
 <file path="C:\Hello\Demo.cs" />
</duplication>
</xml>
```

So if duplication node contains .Designer.cs file in file child then i want it to remove the entire node. So the output should be:

```
<xml>
<duplication>
<file path="C:\Hello\Test.Designer.cs" />
<file path="C:\Hello\Demo.Designer.cs" />
</duplication>
</xml>
```

What would be best way to do it? I would be running that on build pipeline in Azure. So i do not want heavy piece of code.

Comment: How about XSLT approach?

Comment: that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="duplication[file[not(ends-with(@path, '.Designer.cs'))]]">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="duplication[file[not(contains(@path, '.Designer.cs'))]]">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: how do i run this? and what if i wanted to add more parameters?

Comment: Azure Logic App., it has Maps functionality.

Comment: i get an error,  XSLT compile error, the files i am accessing is xml verison 1. if i change to version 1.0, it says ends-with() is unknown function

Comment: Azure Logic App. maps support XSLT 1.0, 2.0, and 3.0. When you create a new map, it allows to select version of XSLT

Comment: i am trying to run through console app in C#

Comment: i could find azure logic app as task in my pipeline

Comment: any other way to implement this?

Comment: If you will switch to using `contains()` function instead of the `ends-with()` function in the XSLT. XSLT 1.0 supports that function. So c# wll be able to run that XSLT 1.0 in the console application.

Comment: I added both versions of the XSLT to the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223379/discussion-between-prakash-kumar-and-yitzhak-khabinsky).